# SFML draw() not drawing first object shape

Tags: c++, sfml

I am creating physics simulation engine in C++ and SFML. I encountered issues where I want to draw a vector of objects however draw does not draw first object from the vector. If I want to draw next objects it works fine. Has anybody else had any similar issues?

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "../include/engine.hpp"

int main()
{
    auto engine = new Engine();

    while(engine->isRunning())
    {
        engine->update(0.25f);
        engine->draw();
    }
}
```

`engine.cpp`:

```
#include "../../include/engine.hpp"

Engine::Engine()
    : window("Collision Engine")
{
    generateObjects(totalObjects);                             
}

void Engine::update(float dt)
{
    window.update();
    releaseObject(dt);
    applyConstraint();    
    applyGravity();

    for(int i = 0; i < objectReleaseCount; i++)
        objects[i].updatePosition(dt);
}

void Engine::draw()
{
    window.beginDraw();

    for(int i = 0; i < objectReleaseCount; i++)
        window.draw(objects[i].shape);
    
    window.endDraw();
}

bool Engine::isRunning() const
{
    return window.isOpen();
}

void Engine::generateObjects(int objectsCount)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < objectsCount; i++)
    {
        Sphere object;
        object.radius = 40.0;
        object.color.red = 255;
        object.color.green = 150;
        object.color.blue = 0;
        object.color.opacity = 255;
        objects.push_back(object);
    }
}

void Engine::releaseObject(float dt)
{
    totalTime += dt;
    if(totalTime == releaseTime)
        if(objectReleaseCount < totalObjects)
        {
            objectReleaseCount++;
            totalTime = 0;
        }
}

void Engine::applyGravity()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < objectReleaseCount; i++)
        objects[i].accelerate(gravity);
}

void Engine::applyConstraint()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < objectReleaseCount; i++)
    {
        sf::Vector2f position = objects[i].position.current;
        sf::Vector2f size(objects[i].radius * 2, objects[i].radius * 2);

        // Left border
        if (position.x - size.x < 0) 
            position.x = size.x; 

        // Right border
        if (position.x + size.x > window.screenWidth) 
            position.x = window.screenWidth - size.x; 

        // Top border
        if (position.y - size.y < 0) 
            position.y = -size.y; 

        // Bottom border
        if (position.y + size.y > window.screenHeight) 
            position.y = window.screenHeight - size.y; 

        objects[i].position.current = position;
    }
}
```

`engine.hpp`:

```
#ifndef ENGINE_HPP
#define ENGINE_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <math.h>

#include "window.hpp"
#include "workingDirectory.hpp"
#include "sphere.hpp"

class Engine
{
    public:
        Engine();
        void update(float dt);
        void draw();
        bool isRunning() const;

        void generateObjects(int count);
        void releaseObject(float dt);
        void applyGravity();
        void applyConstraint();
        
    private:
        Window window;
        WorkingDirectory workingDir;
        std::vector<Sphere> objects;

        sf::Vector2f gravity = {-1.0f, 1.0f};

        int objectReleaseCount = 1;  
        int totalObjects = 2;
        float totalTime = 0;
        float releaseTime = 40.0f;
}; 

#endif
```

`sphere.cpp`:

```
#include "../../include/sphere.hpp"

Sphere::Sphere()
{
    shape.setRadius(radius);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(color.red, 
                                 color.green, 
                                 color.blue, 
                                 color.opacity));    
    setInitialPosition(position.initial);
}

void Sphere::updatePosition(float dt)
{
    velocity = position.current - position.previous;

    position.previous = position.current;

    position.current = position.current + velocity + acceleration * dt * dt;

    shape.setPosition(position.current);
    
    std::cout << "Position = x: " << position.current.x << "y: " << position.current.y << std::endl; 

    acceleration = {};
}

void Sphere::setInitialPosition(sf::Vector2f newPosition)
{
    position.current = position.initial;

    position.previous = newPosition;

    shape.setPosition(newPosition);
}

void Sphere::accelerate(sf::Vector2f acc)
{
    acceleration += acc;
}
```

`sphere.hpp`:

```
#ifndef SPHERE_HPP
#define SPHERE_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "window.hpp"

class Sphere
{
    public:
        Sphere();
        void updatePosition(float dt);
        void setInitialPosition(sf::Vector2f newPosition);
        void accelerate(sf::Vector2f acc);

        // Custom shape
        sf::CircleShape shape; 
        int radius;
        struct 
        {
            sf::Uint8 red = 255;
            sf::Uint8 green = 0;
            sf::Uint8 blue = 255;
            sf::Uint8 opacity = 255;
        } color;   

        struct 
        {
            sf::Vector2f initial {400.0f, 100.0f};
            sf::Vector2f current;
            sf::Vector2f previous;
        } position;

        sf::Vector2f velocity;

        sf::Vector2f acceleration;
};

#endif
```

I tried making an object inside `draw()` function and it worked however it does not work when I want to access objects variable declared inside `.hpp` file.

Comment: Totally unrelated: Don't use `new` unless you have to. `auto engine = new Engine();` could be `Engine engine;` and it would reduce your memory management woes.

Comment: Totally unrelated: simplify `generateObjects` and eliminate the risk of incompletely defined `Sphere`s by giving `Sphere` a smarter constructor.

Comment: Not so unrelated: Take advantage of `objects.size()` (or use [range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)) rather than having to maintain separate counters.

Comment: Actually that is totally related.  The error comes from the use of `objectReleaseCount` instead of `objects.size()`, for its name and use in other places, `objectReleaseCount` was meant for a totally different usage.  Use  `objects.size()` as an upper limit for looping, of better yet, use ranged for loops, as is `for (auto& obj : objects) {...}`, and the bug will disappear.   As for the proper usage of `objectReleaseCount`, it's hard to tell now that most of the code is faulty.

Comment: SFML programs should *always* implement displaying of a frame as a `clear()`, `draw()` (everything), `display()` triplet. I don't see that being done here.. See https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/graphics-draw.php

Comment: Thank you guys for all the feedback! I will apply your suggestions they may solve this issue

Answer (score -1):

Moving some functions from `generateObjects()` to `Sphere` constructor solved this issue.

> The error comes from the use of `objectReleaseCount` instead of `objects.size()`, for its name and use in other places, `objectReleaseCount` was meant for a totally different usage. Use `objects.size()` as an upper limit for looping, of better yet, use ranged for loops, as is `for (auto& obj : objects) {...}`, and the bug will disappear.